# How do I declare dropZone element in AngularJS version of File Upload?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

Using AngularJS version of File Upload (https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html) I'm trying to figure out how I can declare dropZone via HTML attributes - an equivalent of:

```
$(el).fileupload({
  dropZone: $('.dropZone', this)
})
```

Comment: What version you meant ? Can you provide a link to their github repo ?

Comment: Corrected the link in original post. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On their [wiki section](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) they list an angular directive as a fork.

If you go to their [usage section](https://github.com/DominicBoettger/jQuery-File-Upload#usage) on their github repository, you will see that they had created a directive you can use this way:

```
<ng-upload-form url="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" auto-upload="true" size-limit="500000"></ng-upload-form>
```

I think that should help you.

Comment: OK, thanks - so that's why I overlooked this directive - it's bundled into app.js rather than other directives and providers. Nonetheless, as it seems by the scope declaration, there's no attribute designed to sneak in the drop zone, which is by default bound to the main element.

Comment: Great; so did you finally accomplish what you were asking ? In that case, please accept the answer. If not, let me know how can I help

Comment: To be precise, I have not accomplished what I asked for, but your answer gave me a hint. If no one chimes in with a workaround or a better answer, I will accept yours. Relax. And thanks.